# aws mobile sdk for unity- How do I get the progress of download from amazon server(using amazon s3)

Tags: amazon-web-services, unity-game-engine, amazon-s3

I am using aws unity sdk for my unity game to download the assets stored in amazon server.I used GetObjectAsync() for download.In the aws sdk for iOS,we get the progress value from NSUrlSessionDelegates.But I want to use aws mobile sdk for unity and get the progress value of download.How do I do this? Please help.

```
private void GetObject()
{
    ResultText.text = string.Format("fetching {0} from bucket {1}",
    SampleFileName, S3BucketName);
    Client.GetObjectAsync(S3BucketName, SampleFileName, (responseObj) =>
    {
       string data = null;
       var response = responseObj.Response;
       if (response.ResponseStream != null)
       {
          using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.ResponseStream))
          {
             data = reader.ReadToEnd();
          }

          ResultText.text += "\n";
          ResultText.text += data;
       }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that. Here is [snippet](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/E_Amazon_S3_Transfer_TransferUtilityDownloadRequest_WriteObjectProgressEvent.htm) from Amazon develper website.

```
public event EventHandler<WriteObjectProgressArgs> WriteObjectProgressEvent

TransferUtilityDownloadRequest request = new TransferUtilityDownloadRequest();
request.WriteObjectProgressEvent += displayProgress;

private void displayProgress(object sender, WriteObjectProgressArgs args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(args);
}
```

Comment: I can use only aws sdk for unity, not aws sdk for .net.

Comment: @ArchithaShastry ok. Why can't you download this with unity WWW class?

Comment: I think to download using WWW class all your files stored have to be public, which in my case is not.

Comment: @ArchithaShastry That makes sense. Will update answer if I come up with something.

Comment: I am trying to use WWW class by specifying url to object stored in amazon server. url format://<domain name>/object name?AWSKeyId=<accesskey>&Signature=<signature-string>.When I go to the url I get this error---- AccessDeniedRequest has expired1971-01-01T00:00:00Z2016-04-27T03:48:20ZB0EBF805873DEFEF5Sl0i3LRXO03cIdkhvSQuBdnhdm1RhS0xHvyqVVhaC/j7qUVcvYlLO2cjvz0MbaP/CLIFMa1v0c=.I think it is because url is getting expired before I try to access the server.So how do I give the current date and time followed by some extra time interval for "Expires"field?

Comment: I got the url format from link    http://www.bucketexplorer.com/documentation/amazon-s3--how-to-generate-url-for-amazon-s3-files.html

Comment: @ArchithaShastry I don't know Amazon's S3 protocol but according to them, you can do it with WWW. They said you must sign the url and use the presigned url and I have no idea what that means.

Comment: @ArchithaShastry What link?

Comment: http://www.bucketexplorer.com/documentation/amazon-s3--how-to-generate-url-for-amazon-s3-files.html

Comment: You have to specify the expiration time with  `Expires =1301234062`. I don't know how the format of the date but you can try YearMonthDayHourMinute format.

Comment: The link should look something like this `http://<domainname>/objectname ?AWSAccessKeyId =<accesskey>& Expires =<expire time>& Signature =<signature string>`

Comment: I tried YearMonthDayHourMinute format.But not working.

Comment: Can we specify "System.DateTime.Now.AddMinutes (5)" somehow in the url?I know this is a very foolish question..:p

Comment: @ArchithaShastry Lol that's not a foolish question. You can do that but you have to format the result to remove other characters. You have to ask on Amazon website the format of their data as that is very important. I don't know if it is year_month_day_time....You have to ask them this. The date provided in the example seems to the 10 deimcals. 2 for each date/time. The code below may work `System.DateTime dateTime = System.DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10);
        string futureTime = dateTime.ToString("MMddhhmmyy");
        Debug.Log("Future Date: " + futureTime);`

Comment: Then put `futureTime`  in the `<expire time>`.

Comment: @ArchithaShastry I realized you got it working.  `System.Int32 tempTimestamp = (System.Int32)(System.DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10).Subtract(new System.DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;
        string unixTimestamp = tempTimestamp.ToString();` Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I tried to ask on AWS forum.

Unfortunately they doesn't support yet.

Here the link:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=248187&tstart=0

To access of forum is necessary to login.